# ¿Cómo puedo redondear un número en React Native?

Tags: react-native, redondeo

¿Cómo puedo quitar decimal en react native? Este es el cálculo:

```
calculateSum = () => {

    const { peso, altura } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      imc: (Number(peso) / (Number(altura)*Number(altura))) * 10000
    });
}
```

me muestra por ejemplo 24,8787321837812 y solo quiero que me entregue 2 decimales 24,87.

Intenté con el método `toFixed()` pero no me resultó:

```
var value = 10;
value = value.toFixed(2);
this.setState({subTotal: value});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React es una biblioteca JavaScript, y en JavaScript existe el método estándar [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed) para dar formato a los decimales. Tan sólo tendrías que aplicar esa función en tu código cuando asignas `imc` y ya te debería funcionar:

```
calculateSum = () => {
  const { peso, altura } = this.state;

  this.setState({
    imc: ((Number(peso) / (Number(altura)*Number(altura))) * 10000).toFixed(2);
  });
}
```